# What are correct potential answers to this HTML/images assignment?

Tags: html

Today my exam paper was showed and I failed in ICT subject. I wrote 2 question's answer about html solving! (or you can say I had to write HTML for those question in answer paper).

In the question's detail there was wrote:-

> A boy designed a web page where he used a 500*400p image named sunset.png . If the browser can not able to show that pic then it will show "missing" text in the browser window. Then he showed this to his friend. Then his friend do something so when click in the picture then he will go to youtube.
>
> Question no.1:-
>
> Write the html code that the 1st boy used.
>
> Question no.2:-
>
> Write the HTML code that 2nd boy used.

For the 1st question I wrote:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>My webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src="sunset.png" width="500" height="300" alt="missing"></p>
</body>  
</html>
```

for the 2nd question I wrote:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>My webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> <a href="https://www.youtube.com"> <img src="sunset.png" width="500"height="300" alt="missing"> </a> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

My sir told my mistook was `<p>` tag. I can not use paragraph tag outside of image. so, out of 7 I got 0 marks. So, I want to know that was true? Then why the browser showing the pic?

If you have any reference that day you can use `<p>` outside of `<img>` tag please give me that site's link too. so, I can take screen shot and show him.

Comment: Text speak _and_ urgent begging of volunteers? Hmm, a risky strategy on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why bro? Am I wrong?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:
Height is 400 instead of 300.
The

tag defines a paragraph. so that you can tweak it in CSS.
An image doesnt need to be a child of a

tag and if i'm not mistaken it is actually forbidden to do so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang="en">
    <HEAD>
        <title>My webpage</title>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <IMG src="sunset.png" width="500" height="400" alt="missing">
    </BODY>  
</HTML>
```

Other than the previous corrections question 2 is fine.
Maybe consider taking out the Title tag since it isn't stated in the question but it should be okay to leave it in.